# How to handle all file types with my Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to be able to rename, copy, move, etc. any kind of files in my Windows Phone 8.1 app. Is there any way to declare in package manifest, that my app can handle all file types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of information you will find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967755.aspx).

You can access all files that are in your *Application install directory* and *Application data locations*. If you want to access files on *Removable Storage* or *KnownFolders* you will have to spcecify *File type association* in your *packageappx.manifest* file:

> The files your app can access are limited to specific file types that are specified via File Type Association declarations in your app manifest.

You can also access files on your phone via [File pckers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771180.aspx).

Comment: Does that means that I can't show list of all files on SD card, for example?

Comment: @bonzaster Yes - you won't be able to see all files, only those that you have declared association.

Comment: It's unfair! Why Microsoft's app *Files* can see all files, but custom developed apps don't?

Comment: @bonzaster I guess you will have to ask Microsoft. It's not so bad unless you want to make a file manager, most of apps are dedicated to specified file types and comparing to WP8.0 and WP7 restrictions - now it's far more better.